# jOOQ aggregation functions in postgresql

Tags: java, jooq, postgresql-9.4

Postgresql 9.4.5
jOOQ 3.7.2
dialect set to POSTGRES_9_4

I am trying to use jOOQ to wrap replace this native postgresql aggregate expression:

`array_agg(row_to_json(foo) order by "foo"."name" asc) filter (where "attribute".name is not null)`

The jOOQ DSL looks like it should be work using this code:

`arrayAgg(rowToJson(FOO)).orderBy(FOO.NAME).filterWhere(FOO.NAME.isNotNull()))`

Where rowToJson is a wrapper for the postgres function. The SQL this renders is this:

`array_agg(row_to_json(foo) order by "foo"."name" asc)`

Currently I'm working around it with this:

```
public static <T> Field<T[]> arrayAgg(Field<T> field, final SortField<?> sort, final Condition filter) {
    return field("array_agg({0} order by {1}) filter (where {2})", field.getDataType().getArrayDataType(), field, sort, filter);
}
```

The question is, is the first code meant to work? If not, what is the correct way to generate this aggregate function in jOOQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in jOOQ ([#5158](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5158)) and will be fixed in the next releases.

There are two workarounds that I can think of:

- The one you've suggested yourself: Using plain SQL to re-implement the functionality correctly.
- By emulating `FILTER` with `CASE`:

  ```
  arrayRemove(
      arrayAgg(when(FOO.NAME.isNotNull(), rowToJson(FOO))).orderBy(FOO.NAME))
      , null
  )
  ```

  See [`PostgresDSL.arrayRemove()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/util/postgres/PostgresDSL.html#arrayRemove-org.jooq.Field-T-)